# Editing bundle product page

Tags: xml

i'm still new in magento 2 and i want to edit layout of bundle product page of magento 2, so i extend xml file of magento 2 from module-bundle. i create folder Magento_Bundle/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml on my custom Theme and then put this code inside

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="bundle.options.container" destination="content" after="product.info.main"/>
        <move element="product.info.media" destination="content" before="-"/>
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="bundle.options.container" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

i've already flush the cache but nothing change. Is it my xml code wrong ? or maybe something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the below CLI command and check.

```
rm -rf ./var/cache/*
rm -rf ./pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade  
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Note: Also add proper destination, where you want to move.

Comment: it still the same, nothing is change it should be change the layout into
```<div class="product media">...</div>```
```<div class="product-info-main">...</div>```
```<div class="bundle-options-container>...</div>```

isn't it ?